# How to write a script to detect active buttons on a website?

Tags: javascript, java, button, scripting, detection

I am trying to find out a way to write an external script that will run on my computer and preform a specific action. The script needs to access my google chrome, a specific tab, and check the code of the website for a button property change. Ones the button's property changes i want the script to press the button. I am sure that the detection itself is easy, I'm just not sure how to write an external scrip that will access Chrome.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "detect"?  How do you intend for this to work?

Comment: Detect... what? How is a button's state defined? How is a button "active"?

Comment: @LittleB0Y can you change your webpage?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer The button changes a color, from being grayed out to being red. I know how to write a code for that, the detecting it self is easy. I'm just not sure how to write an external script that will run on my computer, will access chrome and press it.

Comment: @LittleB0Y then you  might just want to *explain everything in the post*. The post has an edit button ya'know! :D

Comment: Maybe you should start looking into something like Greasemonkey. It sounds like you're talking about something you want to have your browser do, but there's no single answer about how to do that because each browser is different.

Comment: @LittleB0Y maybe selenium can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an outside code to do things for you (read, automate), and you are trying to do it on a website, I suggest looking into Selenium.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks bud

Comment: Anytime =) I am currently using Appium (Selenium backend) for app testing so that's how I know lol. Lemme know if you need any pointers.

Comment: I actually feel kinda stupid now.. I have used Selenium before back in college in my mobile web dev, for testing apps. Totaly forgot about it. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments i came to the conclusion you just want your button to be clicked when it hits 0 (which it seems you have already done) if that is the case: (sorry if read it wrong question is not very clear)

you can use 2 different ways one is

javascript

```
    var l = document.getElementById('your-button-id');
    l.click();
```

another is using the `trigger` functionality with `jQuery`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("yourbuttonid").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: I updated my thread, i know how to do that if its my own website, in my own code. What i want is a script that will run ether on my computer or my browser (chrome), and will press that button on a site that i do not own.

Comment: well thats a different factor completely.. thats a external plug in which you would need the user to have downloaded im guessing but that is out of scope for us to answer the whole question for you.. sorry.

Comment: The plug is for my self. I'm just trying to figure out how to even begin writing it, and in what language.